# Mysql - Union show tables?

Tags: mysql, select, union

Is there any way of listing all tables and columns names using UNION or a JOIN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want all tables and columns in a schema, no need to use UNION and BIND, just joining the data in

- information_schema.columns
- information_schema.tables

will do the trick.  See details on both at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

An example query that would achieve the minimum of what appears to be your goal would be:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

But again, joining the two based on table name might be needed -- depends on your precise goal.

If you just want the tables with UNION/BIND in the names and the columns with UNION/BIND in the names, two simple queries to do that would be:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%UNION%' or TABLE_NAME LIKE '%BIND%'
```

and

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%UNION%' or TABLE_NAME LIKE '%BIND%'
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not trying to list all tables and columns at the same time, sorry for being unclear. I'll give that a shot, thanks again!

Comment: I see -- I wasn't sure how to read your question.  I updated my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA. The query below would be useful:

```
SELECT 'COLUMN' as Match_Type, 
       column_name as MATCH_NAME, 
       table_name, 
       table_schema
 FROM INFORMATION_sCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%UNION%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%BIND%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE' as Match_Type, 
        table_name  as MATCH_NAME, 
        table_name, 
        table_schema
 FROM INFORMATION_sCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%UNION%'
   OR TABLE_NAME LIKE '%BIND%'
```